# google query dynamic range specification

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a google query which uses a variable range. Here's a part of the query

```
  =query({INDIRECT(V2),arrayformula(row(INDIRECT(V2)))}, "select Col2,
```

where V2 contains

```
  ="Trades!A2:N"&getTradesLastRow()
```

trying to figure out a way to not have the extra reference to V2. Having trouble with the syntax when I try to change the query parameter to be something like

```
  =query({Trades!A2:N&getTradesLastRow(),arrayformula(row(Trades!A2:N&getTradesLastRow()))}, "select Col2,
```

Comment: You missed `INDIRECT` in the last formula.

Comment: Have you tried changing the scope of `arrayformula` to include both the first and second references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use indirect like you had originally in V2

```
=query({INDIRECT(V2),arrayformula(row(INDIRECT("Trades!A2:N"&getTradesLastRow())))}, "select Col2,
```

Comment: that worked. It initially flagged it as a reference error. Then it starts working.  I guess the javascript had to complete before the query becomes valid perhaps.  Thank you.